# postgresql unable to login to postgres admin user and setting auth to trust didn't help (MacOS)

Tags: postgresql, macos

I have screwed up my access to local postgresql installation by altering `postgres` user password to `null` and now i am unable to access postgresql at all. I have already fixed up my pa_hba.conf to `trust` as follows:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all             all                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/32              trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I have restarted postgres with `brew services restart postgres` and that didn't work... so I just rebooted my Mac... that also didn't work.

my authentication attempts look like this:

```
psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I did notice that the following:

```
which postgres
/usr/local/bin/postgres
```

`/usr/local/bin/postgres` does not exist and the config that I'm modifying is located at `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf`

Prerequisite information:

```
postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.1
```

OS: `MacOS`

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out...

First I had to go through the following in order to completely purge my system of PG: http://hzchirs-blog.logdown.com/posts/142678-how-completely-uninstall-postgresql-9x-on-mac-osx

Next, I had the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432”?:
```

The above error was not solvable via any available online miethod that I could find... which was all leeding me to delete a `postmaster.pid` file which did not exist in the first place...

The solution for the above was to add the `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost` stanza to my host file, which come to find out, I was missing almost all of my host file entries that i cared so deeply about (I blame the security team for pushing their stupid updates)...

After that, I was finally able to run `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start` and start-up psql, then log in and set up my users/DBs with `psql postgres`.

Before solving the above issue, I was seeing `could not translate host name "localhost", service "5432" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Buuut it's working now folks!